# Struts html:checkbox query

Tags: java, struts

I have the following code:

```
<td> <html:checkbox name="userForm" property="isActive" /></td>
```

In the form I have a property called `isActive` of type `char`, how would I get the checked value?  I am getting some symbols like `o` if checked.

I am using userform.getIsActive().  Where am I going wrong?  I want 'y' or 'n' values.

Comment: Added the struts tag so Struts people notice it.

Answer (score 3):

By default, when an HTML form containing a checkbox is submitted, if the checkbox is checked the value that gets sent is the string "**on**", and if it's not checked there is no field for that checkbox *at all* in the form data. So you test for the presence of a value, or the absense of one.

You can change what value gets sent when the checkbox is checked by using the `value` attribute (which works both on a standard HTML tag and on a Struts `html:checkbox` tag, according to the [Struts docs](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/checkbox.html)). You can't, with standard HTML, specify that a value should be sent if the checkbox is not checked.

I'm a bit confused at your saying you're getting "o" back. The Struts docs say the corresponding property will be a `boolean`, not a `String`.

Comment: But isgetActive is returning me just 'o' not on .

Comment: @sarah: That's very strange, the docs even reiterate the default value of `value`: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/checkbox.html  But shouldn't it be coming back as a boolean, not a String, anyway? That's what the docs say. (I'm not a Struts person. In fact, at first I missed that this related to Struts.)

Answer (score 1):

If the isActive property on the form is of type char, it can hold only one character. Perhaps that's why the "on" value is being truncated to "o" in your case.

In any case, I'd advise you to change the property datatype to boolean on the form. It's just easier and more logical that way. Whenever you want to use the value from the form, you can very easily do `(form.getIsActive()?"y":"n")` or something like that in your Java code, if you *must* get the value in that exact format. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To make up the strange behaviour of check boxes of HTML form,reset method is given for static form beans in struts 1.x.

Even if checkbox is there on web form, if the form-bean is in request scope there is no need of reset method in form-bean class.

If form-bean is in session scope (which is by default )and its corresponding web form has check box(es),reset method is required in formbeans.